# Xcode Swift Quick Help Closures

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode 8 features auto descriptions, I have created my own documentation and I wanted to fill in the description / data / response / error section.  Here is the screen shot and my question is how does Apple get the information into the box?  I can't find any documentation on this at all.[image: Screen shot of quick help]

Comment: What "box" are you talking about?

Comment: I think he means the table at the bottom of the screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38669725/1271826 (though, admittedly,  the answer there is not entirely satisfying).

Answer (score -1):

NSHipster has a nice writeup on how to create inline documentation for Swift code:

http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/

Here is an excerpt:

```
/// The total distance travelled by the bicycle, in meters.
private(set) var distanceTravelled: Double

/**
    Initializes a new bicycle with the provided parts and specifications.

    - Parameters:
        - style: The style of the bicycle
        - gearing: The gearing of the bicycle
        - handlebar: The handlebar of the bicycle
        - frameSize: The frame size of the bicycle, in centimeters

    - Returns: A beautiful, brand-new bicycle, custom built
      just for you.
*/
init(style: Style, gearing: Gearing, handlebar: Handlebar, frameSize centimeters: Int) {
    self.style = style
    self.gearing = gearing
    self.handlebar = handlebar
    self.frameSize = centimeters

    self.numberOfTrips = 0
    self.distanceTravelled = 0
}
```

There are a host of other examples and options detailed in that post.

Comments formatter like this will populate the documentation popover that appears when you option-click on a property, class, function etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I did check out NSHipster for the answer but this is not what I was looking for.  I did finally figure it out when I did sometime that I did not except Apple to do.  I had to give the completion block a name, but if the result was the same as another name than the last time the name was used would over ride the first name.

Comment: Your question describes wanting to know how to create inline documentation. Consider revising to indicate that you're actually interested in something to do with closures and named arguments.

Comment: I actually think his question makes it perfectly clear that he was looking for documentation on the closure parameters (i.e. his reference to the "the description / data / response / error section" and that the explicit reference to "closures" in the title of this question). This answer is good, but it does not answer the question here, namely about how to document the parameters of a closure parameter.