# How to document parameters of a closure that's a parameter

Tags: swift3, markdown

My attempt at documenting a closure parameter to a function:

```
/**
    sends the request out.

    - Parameter pzurl: request description including url, method, formdata.
 - Parameter responseProcessor: closure that's on success invokes
 - Parameter json: a json array or dictionary
 - Parameter timestamp: and the same `timestamp` that this function returns
 - parameter failure: closure is invoked when json could not be parsed or remote indicated failure
 - Returns: timestamp to identify responses
 */
internal static func processPZURL(pzurl: PZURL,
                                  responseProcessor:@escaping (_ json:JSON, _ timestamp: TimeInterval) -> (), failure:@escaping (PZError) -> ()) -> TimeInterval {
```

yields "No description"

and I can find no description of how to change that

[image]

[Apple markup documentation <s>of no help</s> is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH2-SW1)

[more documentation from NSHipster that does not address the closure woe](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is broken ever since january 2017 (or never worked in any xcode) per this:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3693
so my question seems to be an up to date version of
[How do you document the parameters of a function's closure parameter in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669725/how-do-you-document-the-parameters-of-a-functions-closure-parameter-in-swift-3)

except answer in that question does not work in xcode 9.2

filed 35881586 with apple