# Xcode 10.2 Swift Error: Function types cannot be represented in Objective-C unless their parameters and returns can be

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode10.2

I updated Xcode to 10.2 today and I got the following errors:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2
>   cannot be represented in Objective-C
>
> Function types cannot be represented in Objective-C unless their parameters and returns can be
>   I don't understand why

It was perfectly fine in 10.1.
This is an example that I have been using for years without any issues.
How can I make this code to compile without errors?

```
@objc public func myFunction(inputString: String, handler:@escaping ((success: Bool, outPut: NSArray)) -> Void) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Is that a member function of a *class?*  – My Xcode 10.2 complains *“Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label”* with the Fix-it *“Replace 'outPut: ' with ''”*

Comment: @MartinR I removed the element label and that solved the issue see the answer from matt

Comment: I know that is does. But if I cannot reproduce the *exact* error message as reported then I wonder if the exact code was posted :)

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, you are right. I simplified it... It should have more than one element in the tuple. it should be: func myFunction(inputString: String, handler:@escaping ((success: Bool, outPut: NSArray)) -> Void) {
    // do stuff
}

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. But please update your question with actual code which produces that error message – that makes it more likely that other people with the same problem find this Q&A and the solution. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: *“Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.”*

Comment: @MartinR I updated the question with the correct code. Thanks

Comment: Now it gets interesting: Your closure argument has an extra pair of parentheses, apparently Swift 4 ignores that but Swift 5 does not. If you remove that extra pair: `handler:@escaping (success: Bool, outPut: NSArray) -> Void` then you'll get a clear error message *“Function types cannot have argument labels; use '_'  before 'outPut'”* already in Swift 4/Xcode 10.1. – So what changed is not the forbidden external parameter names (they are already forbidden in Swift 4), but how the compiler treats the extra pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the phrase `outPut:`. It was always illegal; Swift 5 just tightens up at last.

So:

```
@objc public func myFunction(inputString: String, handler:@escaping (NSArray) -> Void) {
```

Comment: You should not be using NSArray either but that’s a different issue.

Comment: Thank you Matt. It did the trick. Is there any way to assign phrases to the variables that is not illegal?

Comment: @Tibidabo: You can define the parameter as `handler: @escaping (_ output: NSArray) -> Void`. That also allows to *document* the parameter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38669796/1187415.